# What is this piece of code doing with RegEx

Tags: c#, regex

Have been studying a sample source code and I can't understand this part, what is this piece of code doing? Mostly the RegEx part...

in the parameters used, "code" is a string, it is C# source code we are passing in.

```
  Match m = null;
  if ((m = Regex.Match(code, "(?ims)^[/']{2}REFDLL (?<ref>.+?)$")).Success)
  {
    foreach (string refDll in m.Groups["ref"].Value.Split(new char[] { ';', ',' }))
    {
      //2008-06-18 by Jeffrey, remove redundant \r
      string mdfyRefDll = refDll.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "");
      //trim the ending .dll if exists
      if (mdfyRefDll.ToLower().EndsWith(".dll"))
          mdfyRefDll = mdfyRefDll.Substring(0, mdfyRefDll.Length - 4);
      string lcRefDll = mdfyRefDll.ToLower();
      if (lcRefDll == "system.data.linq" || lcRefDll == "system"
          || lcRefDll == "system.xml.linq" || lcRefDll == "system.core")
        continue;
      cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(mdfyRefDll + ".dll");
    }
  }
```

Comment: What's are the value ranges for the `code` variable? Do you have any sample input/output?

Comment: @Lirik : "C# source code" is a sample we can pass to "code"..normal C# code.

Comment: It looks like it's finding all of the `using` statements and adds the appropriate assemblies (which are needed for the referenced libraries) to the compiler parameters. Is there anything more you're trying to understand?

Comment: yeah that's good, thanks.  What does the first line do? the line that says RegEx.Match? if you can explain that one, would be great. Thanks

Comment: Given @acheong87's answer and me running the code with sample C# code in the `code` variable, it doesn't seem like it's matching `using` statements but DLLs referenced via `//REFDLL` "keyword". However, in actual C# code `//REFDLL` is treated as a comment. Do you have any actual C# source code that has `//REFDLL` in it?

Comment: @Lirik :L Thanks for investigation. Nop, haven't seen anything myself eithet with //REFDLL in it, this is the source code I am working on: http://minicsharplab.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this image addresses what's going on in the code you posted:

[image: RefDLL]

Mini C# Lab's project description is as follows:

> A handy tool for simple short C# code running and testing, you can
>   save time on waiting for Visual Studio startup and avoid creating a
>   lot of one-time only project files.

It seems like that project is missing documentation, so it's difficult to extrapolate why the author of the code chose that particular way to add referenced DLLs when there is a [using directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in there already. Perhaps he did it to avoid conflicts with the [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

First, `(?ims)` is specifying options.  `i` triggers case-insensitivity, `m` specifies multi-line mode, and `s` (IIRC) enables the dot-all option, meaning that the wildcard `.` includes newline characters.

Then, `^` asserts, "The string must *begin* here, with no preceding characters..." while the `$` at the end asserts, "The string must *end* here, with no following characters."

The `[/']{2}` matches exactly two of either the slash or single-quote characters, i.e. `//`, `''`, `/'`, and `'/`.

The `REFDLL`  matches exactly what you see.

The `(?<ref>.+?)` matches all remaining characters (the final question mark is unnecessary), and remember, due to the `s` option, this includes newline characters.  This portion is stored in a match named `ref`.

In summary, it's trying to match something like

```
//REFDLL helloworld foobar
```

and stores "helloworld foobar" in `ref`.